# make instruction activity with multi pages

Tags: android

I have already developed my application. But I wanted to give the users a multi-page tutorial, in which you can navigate through using two buttons: Next and Previous.The tutorial is 4 pages long. 
My question is, what would be the best strategy to accomplish this? 
What I have thought of so far is making multiple activities, however adding four activities to the application seems to be too much for this task. Is there a way to have one activity contain four pages of instructions? 
Or should I just replace the current view every time one of the buttons is pressed?

Does anyone have a better idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewPager class, it's native and common in most apps.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

example:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

Comment: Please add some important bits of the links into your answer. Link only answers are discouraged here.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is have multiple Activities, use a `Button` to switch activities, and then have an `onClickListener` for the button, and then fire an `Intent` in the `onClickListener`. This would look like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.startActivity();
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes i know how to switch between activities .. but i was looking for the good and easier best way that app developers use.